# Error de servidor en la aplicación '/WebSite5' No puedo cargar mi website en IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

No puedo visualizar mi website, lo desarrolle en Visual Studio 2017 net framework 4.5, lo estoy intentando probar en un servidor windows server 2012 pero no he tenido exito, ya intente lo que comentan en otros foros pero con problemas similares pero no he tenido exito, urge ayuda.

```
Error de servidor en la aplicación '/WebSite5'.
Error de configuración
Descripción: Error durante el procesamiento de un archivo de configuración requerido para dar servicio a esta solicitud. Revise los detalles de error específicos siguientes y modifique el archivo de configuración en consecuencia.

Mensaje de error del analizador: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

Error de código fuente:


Línea 30:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
Línea 31:       <assemblies>
Línea 32:         <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
Línea 33:       </assemblies>
Línea 34:     </compilation>


Archivo de origen: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite5\web.config    Línea: 32

Rastro al cargar el ensamblado: La información siguiente puede ser útil para determinar porqué no se cargó el ensamblado 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'.


AVS: El registro del enlace de ensamblado está desactivado.
Para habilitar el registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado, establezca el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) como 1.
Nota: existe una disminución del rendimiento asociada registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado.
Para desactivar esta característica, elimine el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Información de versión: Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Versión ASP.NET:4.7.3062.0
```

Comment: Ya intente lo de crear aplicacion con esa misma carpeta pero me sale otro error Es incorrecto utilizar una sección registrada como allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' mas allá del nivel de aplicación.

Comment: Ya revise y efectivamente hay dos web.config, pero tienen contenido diferente, inhabilite el de un subdirectorio pero tampoco funciona

Comment: validaste que en la carpeta \bin del sitio este la dll de MySql.Data ?

Comment: si esta el archivo MySql.Data.dll

Comment: en el IIS defines un web site asignandole un puerto, o lo haces sobre el default en una carpeta? recomendaria crees un sitio con un puerto

Comment: ok dejame intentar

Comment: Hmm. Estamos teniendo problemas para encontrar ese sitio.

No podemos conectarnos al servidor en s.

Si esa dirección está correcta, aquí hay otras tres cosas que puedes probar:

    Vuelve a intentarlo más tarde.
    Revisa tu conexión de red.
    Si estás conectado pero detrás de un firewall, revisa que Firefox

Comment: Corrigeme leandro, en un principio solo copie la carpeta donde aloja el proyecto de visual studio 2017 C:\Users\SISTEMAS02\source\repos\WebSite5, tal cual la copie a C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite5 de mi sevridor, es correcto ese paso?

Comment: con solo copiar no alcanza, si pones una carpeta dentro del default web site del iis tenes que defiir esta como virtual directory

Answer (score 0):

Copiar el contenido a una carpeta del `default web site` del `IIS` no alcanza para que funcione y tome el web.config de esa aplicacion, ya que reconocera solo el del root

Tienes que agregarla como aplicacion al web site, usando la opcion de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces si, el web.config y las librerias que publiques en esa carpeta estaran contenidas como una aplicacion dentro del sitio

[Diferencias entre aplicación y directorio virtual en IIS](http://rm-rf.es/diferencias-entre-aplicacion-y-directorio-virtual-en-iis/)

Es bueno conocer la diferencia entre una `aplicacion` y un `directorio virtual` ya que te permitira definir configuracion en el `Application pool`